# Renaming Files in a Directory From List using R

Tags: directory, rename, file-manipulation

I want to use a csv file with old file names and their new file names to rename files in a directory using R.  I am quite the amateur in R but I'm hoping someone can help.

I've tried to create two character vectors with the names to compare.  I want kind of an if / then statement: "if this file is named x, then rename to y"

```
FileNames <- read.csv("New_FileNamesCSV.csv")

oldNames <- as.character(FileNames$CurrentFileName)

NewNames <- as.character(FileNames$NewFileName)


setwd("F:/Workspace/ (Local)/FileWork/Files")

file.rename(from = oldNames, to = NewNames)
```

This is the error I am getting:

> Error in file.rename(from = oldNames, to = NewNames) :    object
>   'oldNames' not found

Comment: Your OldNames variable is uppoercase, whereas your are using `from=oldNames` (lowercase).

Comment: That must have been a copy and paste error in Stack Overflow.  I get the same error with that corrected